# Calling an interface method that calls another method on the same interface

Tags: unit-testing, go

Say I have the following interface in golang

```
type InterfaceA interface {
   Method1()
   Method2()
}

func (o *Obj) Method1() {
  o.Method2()
}

func (o *Obj) Method2() {
}

obj1 := //instantiate a type that implements the above interface
```

If I am writing unit tests for `Method1`, how can I create a mock object for `Obj` while at the same execute code in `Method1` on a real `Obj` object? The challenge is that `Obj` calls `Method2` which has to be on the mocked object while `Method1` needs to be called on the real object.

Comment: Dont write mocks, test real object.

Comment: I'm unaware of the context but one way to solve this is via dependency injection. Example: https://goplay.space/#R2szkDmsinl

Answer (score 3):

Go doesn't really have dynamic dispatch. The type of `Method1()` receiver `o` is `*Obj` so the expression `o.Method2()` will always call `Obj.Method2()`, the interface is not involved here at all.

So what you want is impossible. But that shouldn't be an issue as we normally unit-test at object level, not method level.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I understand why you want to do this exactly. But You could add the "real" object as a field of the mock object and call its method.

```golang
// the mock object has a field of type Obj
type MockObject struct {
    obj Obj
}

// then it can call the "real" objects method
func (o *MockObject) Method1() {
  o.obj.Method2()
}

func (o *MockObject) Method2() {
}
```

I am doing something like this sometimes to implement an interface. For example, like below. This way I can use the server type and stick it into `ListenAndServe` since it implements `ServeHTTP`.

```golang
type Server struct {
    router  *http.ServeMux
}

func (s *Server) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    s.router.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

func NewServer() *Server {
    return &Server{
        router: http.NewServeMux(),
    }
}

s := NewServer()
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", s)
```